# Identify treatment intensification date

Tags: sas

I have data that looks like -

```
data abc;
input ID $ drug $ episode start_date date9. end_date date9.;
format start_date end_date date9.;
informat start_date end_date date9.;
datalines ;
1 A 1 01Jan2012 30Mar2012
1 A 2 01May2012 03Jul2012
1 A 3 28Sep2012 28Oct2012
1 A 4 01Nov2012 30Dec2012
1 B 1 01Apr2012 10May2012
1 B 2 02Nov2012 28Dec2012
1 B 3 01Jan2012 30Mar2012
1 C 1 01Jul2012 02Aug2012
;
run;
```

Here we have subjects and the the drugs they take. A new episode of one drug means that the person discontinued.

If the start date (start date of 1st episode) of second drug consumed , lies in between the episodes of first drug , then we will ignore all the further episodes of 1st drug.

Eg. here 1 april (start date of drug B) lies after the first episode of drug A, so episode 2,3,4 of drug A would be deleted.

Similarly the start date for drug C lies after the end date of episode 1 for drug B then episode 2 of drug B would be deleted.

The maximum number of episodes a subject can have is 15.

The resultant dataset should look like -

```
ID  Drug    Episode start_date  end_date
1   A   1   1-Jan   30-Mar
1   B   1   1-Apr   10-May
1   C   1   1-Jul   2-Aug
```

Comment: When we consider the first episode of a drug, do we also only consider the first episode of the previous drug? I.e. if the start_date of the first episode for drug B is smaller than the start_date of the first episode for drug A, but larger than the second episode, then what? I assume you want to delete episode 3 and 4 for drug A then?

Comment: Yes , you are right

Comment: How many subjects ? Is there a maximal time frame to the 15 episode limit ?  What have you tried ? Is there a question besides "This is what I want?"

Comment: Why is episode B3 time frame before episode B1 timeframe ? How many subjects ? Is there a maximal time frame to the 15 episode limit ? What have you tried ? Is there a question besides "This is what I want?"

Answer (score 0):

How about this? I added another ID to the example data for demonstration.

```
data abc;
input ID $ drug $ episode start_date :date9. end_date :date9.;
format start_date end_date date9.;
datalines ;
1 A 1 01Jan2012 30Mar2012
1 A 2 01May2012 03Jul2012
1 A 3 28Sep2012 28Oct2012
1 A 4 01Nov2012 30Dec2012
1 B 1 01Apr2012 10May2012
1 B 2 02Nov2012 28Dec2012
1 B 3 01Jan2012 30Mar2012
1 C 1 01Jul2012 02Aug2012
2 A 1 01Jan2012 30Mar2012
2 A 2 01May2012 03Jul2012
2 A 3 28Sep2012 28Oct2012
2 A 4 01Nov2012 30Dec2012
2 B 1 01Apr2012 10May2012
2 B 2 02Nov2012 28Dec2012
2 B 3 01Jan2012 30Mar2012
2 C 1 01Jul2012 02Aug2012
;
run;

data want;

    format ID drug episode start_date end_date;
    keep   ID drug episode start_date end_date;

    declare hash h ();
    h.definekey  ('ID', 'd');
    h.definedata ('_start_date');
    h.definedone ();

    do until (lr1);
        set abc (rename= (start_date = _start_date)) end=lr1;
        by ID drug;
        if first.ID   then d = 0;
        if first.drug then d + 1;
        if episode = 1 then h.add();
    end;

    do until (lr2);
        set abc end=lr2;
        by ID drug;
        if first.ID   then d = 0;
        if first.drug then do;
            d + 1; flag = 0;
        end;
        rc = h.find(key : ID, key : d+1);
        if start_date > _start_date then flag=1;
        if flag = 0 then output;
    end;

    retain flag;
run;
```

Result:

```
ID  drug  episode  start_date  end_date 
1   A     1        01JAN2012   30MAR2012 
1   B     1        01APR2012   10MAY2012 
1   C     1        01JUL2012   02AUG2012 
2   A     1        01JAN2012   30MAR2012 
2   B     1        01APR2012   10MAY2012 
2   C     1        01JUL2012   02AUG2012
```